# send intent to an already running activity

Tags: android

Main Activity has started activity A and A has started activity B, which is currently visible on the screen: Main Activity -> A -> B.

Now Main Activity receives a broadcast intent and it needs to pass new information from it via A to B without restarting A or B, i.e., the state of A and B should remain as is.  For example, if user has written someting to EditText in B, that text should not be lost.

Question: what Intent flags should be used when MainActivity sends intent containing the new information to A and A to B in order to achieve the above described behavior?

Comment: why don't you receive that broadcast directly in Activity A?

Comment: if you want to get action directly on activity B, then register your broadcast receiver on activity B, no need to register broadcast receiver on MainActivity

Comment: And I doubt if you can receive Broadcast when the activity is in Background

Comment: Sure I can receive Broadcast in MainActivity when B is on foregound.  I receive the Broadast in MainActivity, since A and B are not necessarily in the activity stack, when the Broadcast arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Use the activity.startActivity(Intent) method in your Activity B to call activity A ‘s “newIntent(Intent)” method, do with what you need to then :) and maybe make sure in the manifest file the activity is set to SingleInstance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than figthing with intents and launch modes, I decided to save the necessary state of A and B at their onPause() method to a companion object of MainActivity and then restore the state from there at onResume() method of A and B.

Comment: This means to use global variables to pass information. This does not seem like a robust solution.